# Smooth mesh by increasing poly count

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, geometry, polycount

No beveling, I need align it to outer edges. So, this mean automatic subdivision(needed iterations count depends from poly size, and probably nearest faces angle in between). For example make 5 pseudo quads from large tris group (2 in one layer) and move new edges around on calculated distance to reach more round surface of this entire area. Same way for smaller tris in group, this time split it i.e. on 2 parts and do the same. Smallest shape forming polys should not be touched. You know entire logic of this. Which modifier do I need?

Actually gonna correct myself and bump this. Sorry for probably being unclear.
I need this, marked by red lines, on complex surface and automatically:
[image]

Comment: So you want the mesh to be smoother, but you also don't want it to change any of the corners or edges? I'm not sure quite what you are looking for here.

Comment: Yes, that's right, commonly it's cutting edges to smooth the shape, but this is backwise, add more edges to form smooth shape.

Comment: So does the subdivision surface modifier not do what you want?

Comment: It does pretty well. The problem is expanding ALL new edges. And there gonna be many of them. Very. Only way is automatic.

Comment: I just don't know how it handles multiple layers at once. Like cut this part on 6 pieces per poly pair, this only on 4, don't touch this polys etc. And simultaneously move new edges at required positions. Will look into it.

Comment: But it uses average or lower threshold instead of upper. Maybe entire geometry form will not be smaller too much...

Comment: And what is much more crazy thing - OR select craplord of edges to set weightes to keep it 90deg, OR select required areas to modify only them. Which is impossible now by modifiers. Any solution?

Comment: Just fine to use subsurf, if you able to skip various unused edges at random places. Lots of it. This is not just a model to modify. It is very complex thing which needs only partial smoothing. Modifier is not an option.

Answer (score -1):

Actually now realized how to. Cut out needed parts, and smooth with modifier as separate objects. BUT catmull-clark method still has noticeable weakness, it approximates this task, but does NOT works as external only tris. Actually it does pretty counter thing and not only cuts edges to inner side but even completely doesn't touch base edges as anchors. I don't need smoothed geometry to be smaller, at least it's minimal changing.

Comment: I would suggest thinking about clearer communication especially in this complex field of CG. It's difficult if not impossible to understand most of what you write because you skip much of the context and this way don't really say anything because of missing information. For example: "Actually now realized how to."  How to do what? Later: "...it approximates this task..." - the task was not identified in the first place. What task are you talking about?.. Who knows?..  If you say "inner edges" or "base edges" without any context or definition that also has no meaning at all...

Comment: Sorry, now being clear. And also that way was wrong. We need just set some edges around the mesh to Crease=0.2, don't forget about details which requires Crease=1. Then those lines will just keep base geometry at origin positions and will allow smoothing. Resizing is minimal. Now this is answer.